# Continuous Errors in EE developer log

Tags: cartthrob

I'm having these errors in my EE developer log:

```
Deprecated function set_cookie() called in system/expressionengine/third_party/cartthrob/libraries/Cartthrob_session.php on line 195.
```

From template tag exp:cartthrob:__construct in core/article.
This tag may have been parsed from one of these snippets: {snippet_header}, {snippet_header_testing}, {snippet_header_backup_feb_1_2013}, {snippet_header-donation}
Deprecated since 2.8. Use EE_Input::set_cookie() instead.

I'm running latest CT and EE versions. 
is this something that should be ignored?

Comment: I haven't used CartThrob before, but I would check with their support staff to see how you can get rid of these errors.

Answer (score 1):

This might turn out to not be a perfectly clear answer (or in the classical meaning), however:

Is that the only error you are getting? I am asking because my dev-log has more entries (I have a lot of Modules and Add-Ons installed), ranging from NSM Better Meta to Profile:Edit to EE Debug Toolbar and others.

I asked the same question a while ago but can't remember where it was. I was told that I shouldn't worry about it too much, since the dev log errors *should* be something tat devs keep an eye on.

I'm on EE 2.7.3 and CT 2.5 and don't get any CartThrob error logs atm. CartThrob is not yet combatible with 2.8 (they are working on it). So I suppose this is where your errors are coming from. Ace McCarttrhob just recently wrote on twitter:

> ok, that is the best combo at the moment.
> (in reply to a user that said he is on EE 2.7.3 and CT 2.5)

To complete the answer here is what EE writes in the CP popup after clicking on:

*This is a log for developers to bring notices or warnings to the attention of the Super Admins. **What does this mean**?*

> One of two things has happened:
>
> - The system has detected native code or an add-on that is using outdated code that may stop working or cause issues with the system. This means an add-on in your installation is accessing a part of ExpressionEngine's core code which EllisLab plans to remove in the future in order to improve the quality of the product.
> - A warning or message was raised by native code or an add-on for the Super Admin to view.
>
> To remedy this notice, you may need to do any of the following:
>
> - Contact the developer who manages your ExpressionEngine installation for help
> - Make sure you have the latest version of all your installed add-ons
> - Contact the developer of the offending add-on to make sure they're aware of the problem and plans to issue an update

Comment: Thanks for detailed answer Marc. Yes I have pretty long error log which is almost full of this error coming from Carthrob. I think as you said "They are still working on it" I think that makes sense - so at some stage the add-on needs to be upgraded I guess.